# Sequence doesn't count upwards

Tags: java, dictionary, sequence, talend

I have following piece of code, which basically does append everything corect, but the Sequence doesn't count upwards. Any Idea whats wrong there?

```
globalMap.containsKey(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase()) ?
    (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase()) :
    (globalMap.put(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase(), row1.File_Name.toUpperCase() + 
       "-ID-" + Numeric.sequence(row1.File_Name, 1, +1).toString()) == null ?
    (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase()) :
    (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase())
```

Thanks in advance for advice!

Comment: Why would you write code like this?? Especially the second ternary operator is a really ugly hack... If you just split it into parts, you can probably easily pinpoint what's going wrong.

Comment: It's not considered good practice to have statements used in a ternary operator have side effects.  I think the code would be easier to understand and reason about if you used some `if` blocks ...

Comment: shouldn't this part be one isolated part? Numeric.sequence(row1.File_Name, 1, +1).toString()) == null ?
    (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase() ")" :
    (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase()). there is a bracket that should not be there. i marked it with ""

Comment: Yeah I agree, thats all a bit weird code, I'd never put it as this when writing it all by myself.
The main issue for the ternary is, that talend open studio seems to have problems with if-conditions rather than with ternary

Comment: I somehow doubt that talend has issues with if statements. Are you sure it wasn't something silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, figured it out - had to switch the true and false conditions, as I wanted to count up the same ones.

I guess my brain was too messed up yesterday - new day, refreshed brain, and done.

```
globalMap.containsKey(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase()) ?
    (globalMap.put(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase(), row1.File_Name.toUpperCase() + 
       "-ID-" + Numeric.sequence(row1.File_Name, 1, +1).toString()) == null ?
            (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase()) :
            (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase()) 
    ):
    (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are actually incrementing any value repeatedly, maybe this is why your sequence is not increasing.

```
if(globalMap.containsKey(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase())){
    (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase())
}else{
    if((globalMap.put(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase(), row1.File_Name.toUpperCase() + 
   "-ID-" + Numeric.sequence(row1.File_Name, 1, +1).toString()) == null){
        (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase());
    }else{
        (String)globalMap.get(row1.File_Name.toUpperCase())
    }
}
```

Here's what your code would look like with if/else statements. I did not compile this code, and am not sure it would compile as I can't track those parenthesis easily.